# How to find out Lotus Fields DataType?

Tags: c#, com, lotus-notes

I have following code to access Lotus Form's Fields(COM Interop), But i am unable to get its dataType.(e.g. : Text , Number , DataTime)

```
        NotesSession notesSessionClass = new NotesSession();
        notesSessionClass.Initialize(pPassword);
        NotesDatabase pNotesDatabase= notesSessionClass.GetDatabase("", pDatabaseName, false);
        object objectForms = pNotesDatabase.Forms;
        Array formArray = (System.Array)objectForms;

        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < formArray.Length; cnt++)
        {
            NotesForm localForm = (NotesForm)formArray.GetValue(cnt);

            Array fieldsArray = (System.Array)localForm.Fields;
            for (int fieldCnt = 0; fieldCnt < fieldsArray.Length; fieldCnt++)
            {
                string field = (string)fieldsArray.GetValue(fieldCnt);
                FIELD_TYPE fieldType = localForm.GetFieldType(field);
                string strFieldType = fieldType.ToString();
             }
         }
```

Comment: What errors or unexpected values are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public enum MyLotusFieldType
 {
    //http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_TYPE_PROPERTY_ITEM.html

    // Legal values
    ACTIONCD = 16,// means saved action CD records; non-Computable; canonical form. 
    ASSISTANTINFO = 17,// means saved assistant information; non-Computable; canonical form. 
    ATTACHMENT = 1084,// means file attachment. 
    AUTHORS = 1076,// means authors. 
    COLLATION = 2,//. 


    // Note This value is new with Release 6
    DATETIMES = 1024, //means date-time value or range of date-time values. 
    EMBEDDEDOBJECT = 1090, //means embedded object. 
    ERRORITEM = 256, //means an error occurred while accessing the type. 
    FORMULA = 1536, //means Notes formula. 
    HTML = 21, //means HTML source text. 
    ICON = 6, //means icon. 
    LSOBJECT = 20, //means saved LotusScript Object code for an agent. 
    MIME_PART = 25, //means MIME support. 
    NAMES = 1074, //means names. 
    NOTELINKS = 7, //means link to a database, view, or document. 
    NOTEREFS = 4, //means reference to the parent document. 
    NUMBERS = 768, //means number or number list. 
    OTHEROBJECT = 1085, //means other object. 
    QUERYCD = 15, //means saved query CD records; non-Computable; canonical form. 
    READERS = 1075, //means readers. 
    RFC822Text = 1282, //means RFC822 Internet mail text. 
    RICHTEXT = 1, //means rich text. 
    SIGNATURE = 8, //means signature. 
    TEXT = 1280, //means text or text list. 
    UNAVAILABLE = 512, //means the item type isn't available. 
    UNKNOWN = 0, //means the item type isn't known. 
    USERDATA = 14, //means user data. 
    USERID = 1792, //means user ID name. 
    VIEWMAPDATA = 18, //means saved ViewMap dataset; non-Computable; canonical form. 
    VIEWMAPLAYOUT = 19 //means saved ViewMap layout; non-Computable; canonical form

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`GetFieldType` returns an integer. The possible values are explaned in the documentation of [NotesItem.Type](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_TYPE_PROPERTY_ITEM.html).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a "secret feature" that adds 1 to the type value when the field is a list or multi-value item. So if you're getting 1281, it's telling you it's a text list. That's the rumor!